# Scala, position objects on a circumference

Tags: oop, scala, cycle

I am trying to populate a circumference with points located at equal intervals. Here is the code (it uses some Processing, but it is not crucial for understanding):

```
class Circle (x: Float, y: Float, subdivisions: Int, radius: Float) extends WorldObject(x, y) {

  def subs = subdivisions
  def r = radius
  val d = r + r

  def makePoints() : List[Glyph] = { 
    val step = PConstants.TWO_PI / subdivisions
    val points = List.make(subdivisions, new Glyph())

    for(i <- 0 to subdivisions - 1) {
      points(i) position (PApplet.cos(step * i) * r + xPos, PApplet.sin(step * i) * r + yPos)
    }

    points
  }

  val points: List[Glyph] = makePoints()

  override def draw() {
    applet fill 0
    applet stroke 255
    applet ellipse(x, y, d, d)
    applet fill 255

    points map(_.update())
  }

}

class Glyph(x: Float, y: Float) extends WorldObject(x, y){
    def this() = this(0, 0)

    override def draw() {
      applet ellipse(xPos, yPos, 10, 10)
    }
}

object WorldObject {

}

abstract class WorldObject(var xPos: Float, var yPos: Float) {
  def this() = this(0, 0)
  def x = xPos
  def y = yPos

  def update() {
    draw()
  }

  def draw()

  def position(x: Float, y: Float) {
    xPos = x
    yPos = y
  }

  def move(dx: Float, dy: Float) {
    xPos += dx
    yPos += dy
  }
}
```

The strange result that I get is that all the points are located at a single place. I have experimented with `println` checks... the checks in the `makePoints()` method shows everything ok, but checks in the `Circle.draw()` or even right after the `makePoints()` show the result as I see it on the screen - all points are located in a single place, right where the last of them is generated, namely `x=430.9017 y=204.89435` for a circle positioned at `x=400 y=300` and subdivided to 5 points. So somehow they all get collected into the place where the last of them sits.

Why is there such a behavior? What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPD:** We have been able to locate the reason, see below:

Answering the question, user unknown changed the code to use the `fill` method instead of `make`. The main relevant difference between them is that `make` pre-computes it's arguments and `fill` does not. Thus `make` fills the list with totally identical items. However, `fill` repeats the computation on each addition. Here are the source codes of these methods from Scala sources:

```
  /** Create a list containing several copies of an element.
   *
   *  @param n    the length of the resulting list
   *  @param elem the element composing the resulting list
   *  @return     a list composed of n elements all equal to elem
   */
  @deprecated("use `fill' instead", "2.8.0")
  def make[A](n: Int, elem: A): List[A] = {
    val b = new ListBuffer[A]
    var i = 0
    while (i < n) {
      b += elem
      i += 1
    }
    b.toList
  }
```

And the `fill` method:

```
  /** Produces a $coll containing the results of some element computation a number of times.
   *  @param   n  the number of elements contained in the $coll.
   *  @param   elem the element computation
   *  @return  A $coll that contains the results of `n` evaluations of `elem`.
   */
  def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: => A): CC[A] = {
    val b = newBuilder[A]
    b.sizeHint(n)
    var i = 0
    while (i < n) {
      b += elem
      i += 1
    }
    b.result
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a lot of variables forth and back (def x = ... => def x () = , x/ this.x and x/xPos and so on) added println statements and removed (P)applet-stuff, which made the compiler complain.

Providing a compilable, runnable, standalone demo would be beneficial. Here it is:

```
class Circle (x: Float, y: Float, subdivisions: Int, radius: Float) 
    extends WorldObject (x, y) {

  def subs = subdivisions
  def r = radius
  val d = r + r

  def makePoints() : List[Glyph] = { 
//    val step = PConstants.TWO_PI / subdivisions
    val step = 6.283F / subdivisions
    val points = List.fill (subdivisions) (new Glyph ())
    for (i <- 0 to subdivisions - 1) {
//      points (i) position (PApplet.cos (step * i) * r + xPos, 
//          PApplet.sin (step * i) * r + yPos)
                val xx = (math.cos (step * i) * r).toFloat + xPos
                val yy = (math.sin (step * i) * r).toFloat + yPos
                println (xx + ": " + yy)
      points (i) position (xx, yy)
    }
    points
  }

  val points: List [Glyph] = makePoints ()
  override def draw () {
  /*
    applet fill 0
    applet stroke 255
    applet ellipse(x, y, d, d)
    applet fill 255
  */
//    println ("Circle:draw () upd-> " + super.x () + "\t" + y () + "\t" + d); 
    points map (_.update ())
    println ("Circle:draw () <-upd " + x + "\t" + y + "\t" + d); 
  }
}

class Glyph (x: Float, y: Float) extends WorldObject (x, y) {
    def this () = this (0, 0)
    override def draw() {
      // applet ellipse (xPos, yPos, 10, 10)
      println ("Glyph:draw (): " + xPos + "\t" + yPos + "\t" + 10); 
    }
}

object Circle {
    def main (as: Array [String]) : Unit = {
        val c = new Circle (400, 300, 5, 100)
        c.draw ()       
    }
}

object WorldObject {

}

abstract class WorldObject (var xPos: Float, var yPos: Float) {

  def this () = this (0, 0)
  def x = xPos
  def y = yPos

  def update () {
    draw ()
  }

  def draw ()

  def position (x: Float, y: Float) {
    xPos = x
    yPos = y
    // println (x + " ?= " + xPos + " ?= " + (this.x ()))
  }

  def move (dx: Float, dy: Float) {
    xPos += dx
    yPos += dy
  }
}
```

My result is:

```
500.0: 300.0
430.9052: 395.1045
319.10266: 358.78452
319.09177: 241.23045
430.8876: 204.88977
Glyph:draw (): 500.0    300.0   10
Glyph:draw (): 430.9052 395.1045    10
Glyph:draw (): 319.10266    358.78452   10
Glyph:draw (): 319.09177    241.23045   10
Glyph:draw (): 430.8876 204.88977   10
Circle:draw () <-upd 400.0  300.0   200.0
```

Can you spot the difference?

You should create a copy of your code, and stepwise remove code, which isn't necessary to reproduce the error, checking, whether the error is still present. Then you should reach a much smaller problem, or find the error yourself.

Comment: Thank you for pointing all this out! It is very logical, and usually I do so, but I think that it is the spirit of novelty in Scala for me, that I cannot see yet how to reduce the problem even more. Sorry for the PApplet inclusions, I did not think that someone will try to run the code.. As for the solution, in your code there is the change from the `make` method of the list to the `fill` method. Now I understand the difference between them. What is strange, I was unable to find any docs on the `make` method of the List or it's superclasses to the extent that I was able to reach.

Comment: I guess fill is primarly a new/better name, introduced with a recent version, while 'make' was used before. It's deprecated in 2.9 so I had to replace it, to make the code compile, but it shouldn't be a differnce. But I don't find a difference, which explains the different results. Maybe partial compilation solved a circular dependency?

Comment: I am using Eclipse with Scala IDE for my work, and it allows ctrl-clicking on a method or variable to see it's declaration. Doing so I was able to locate the declarations of the both methods. They differ in their intent and composition. I have edited the original post and added the descriptions of both - see there.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that it was really the solution for your problem. :)